# Terraform how to change provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Have a question on Terraform,

Suppose i'm using provider "AWS" today and in future i need to change to other cloud provider , what are changes i need to do to my code other than changing provider,

How hard it will be to switch to other provider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the short answer to your question is, pretty hard? Other than just changing the providers, you'd need to change each of the associated resources to the other providers resources.

Resources in Terraform are not provider agnostic. Instead they are very specific to their providers. For example, if you wanted to create an instance using the AWS Provider, you'd use the [`aws_instance`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html) resource. If you wanted to create an instance using the Google Cloud Provider, you'd use the [`google_compute_instance`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_instance.html).

Comment: Happy to help. If this answers your question, you can choose to accept it so that others know it answers the question too :)